# Can I delete the theme twentyfourteen?

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a crash when I upgrade Wordpress. When I reopen it, this error message pop up.

> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/inc/custom-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php on line 496

Now I can enter into management interface  with winscp, how can I rescue my wordpress just to delete the  theme  twentyfourteen?

I delete the wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/, when I open my wordpress, I can see nothing, how can i do now? There are still twentythirteen and twentytwelve in the theme directory, can I use one of them?
If I want  to use twentytwelve, the sql command will work?

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'template'; 
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';     
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';
```

Comment: I delete the wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/ ,when i open my wordpress ,i can see nothing,how can i do now?

Comment: You were using the theme in your site? If so, install the theme again and if the error appears again try a different theme

Comment: how to install the theme?i do not remember my wordpress version.

Comment: upload theme folder in ftp

Comment: There are still twentythirteen and twentytwelve in the theme directory,can i use one of them?

Comment: yes, if you change the theme name in the database through phpadmin or something. But it is easier to just try a fresh set of files of wp without touching the database.

Comment: UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'template';

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'template'; 
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'stylesheet';     
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'twentytwelve' WHERE option_name = 'current_theme';
```

works for me！